# Why is my IE browser getting launched twice with Selenium and Cucumber?

Tags: java, selenium, spring-boot, automation, cucumber

I am writing very basic automation test with `Selenium-Cucumber` that is launching an `IE` browser and closing it at the end.

The problem is that the browser gets launched twice.

The test does not have much it other than few `System.out` statements. I am kind of new to both `selenium`-based automation testing and `Cucumber` and not able to understand why is it getting launched twice.

Please guide.

**BrowserConfig.java**

```
public class BrowserConfig {

    private static final String IE_DRIVER_EXE = "drivers/IEDriverServer.exe";
    private static final String WEBDRIVER_IE_DRIVER = "webdriver.ie.driver";
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.google.com";

    public static WebDriver getIEWebDriver() {
        String filePath = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(IE_DRIVER_EXE).getFile();
        System.setProperty(WEBDRIVER_IE_DRIVER, filePath);
        InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions().requireWindowFocus();
        options.setCapability(INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        options.setCapability(ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP, true);
        options.setCapability(IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        options.setCapability(ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        options.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
        options.setCapability(INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, BASE_URL);
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }

    public static void releaseResources(WebDriver driver) {
        if (null != driver) {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"})
public class TestRunner extends ApplicationTests {

}
```

**LoginStep.java**

```
@Ignore
public class LoginStep {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        if (this.driver == null) {
            this.driver = BrowserConfig.getIEWebDriver();
        }
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        BrowserConfig.releaseResources(driver);
    }

    @Given("^The user is on the Login page$")
    public void doLogin() {
        System.out.println("The user is on the Login page");
    }

    @When("^The user enters the correct credentials on the Login page$")
    public void setWelcomePage() {
        System.out.println("The user enter the correct credentials on the Login page");
    }

    @Then("^The user is displayed Welcome page$")
    public void validate() {
        System.out.println("The user is displayed Welcome page");
    }

}
```

**HelpStep.java**

```
@Ignore
public class HelpStep {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        if (this.driver == null) {
            this.driver = BrowserConfig.getIEWebDriver();
        }
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        BrowserConfig.releaseResources(driver);
    }

    @When("^The user clicks on the Help menu link from the Welcome page$")
    public void setWelcomePage() {
        System.out.println("The user clicks on the Help menu link from the Welcome page");
    }

    @Then("^The user is displayed Help page$")
    public void validate() {
        System.out.println("The user is displayed Help page");
    }

}
```

**help.feature**

```
Feature: Check that the user is able to navigate to Help page

  Background:
    Given The user is on the Login page
    When The user enters the correct credentials on the Login page
    Then The user is displayed Welcome page

  Scenario:
    When The user clicks on the Help menu link from the Welcome page
    Then The user is displayed Help page
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cucumber-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cucumber.version>4.2.3</cucumber.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>3.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>${project.artifactId}</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Why are you using [ie browser](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-IT-Pro-Blog/The-perils-of-using-Internet-Explorer-as-your-default-browser/ba-p/331732)?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of code and step through it until launches each browser.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I prefer Chrome but no choice as it is a legacy application that only works on IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are initializing and call your driver twice in feature files.

`Background` part of your feature file are initializing browser firstly in `LoginStep.java` then your `Scenario` is also initialize browser in `HelpStep.java`.

I prefer using global `Hooks.java` class for `@Before` and `@After` hooks and inject driver between different `.java` classes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Selcuk. Updated with my answer and solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The below sample code is not the same as original post but this fixes the issue. Added new class "Hooks.java" that contains common steps and removed "Background" from feature files. That helped fix the issue.

**Hooks.java**

```
public class Hooks {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("Into the setup method of AccountStep...");
        driver = BrowserConfig.getDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        System.out.println("Into the cleanUp method of AccountStep...");
        if (null != driver) {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

**help.feature**

```
Feature: Check that the user is able to navigate to Help page

  Scenario:
    Given The user is on the Help page
    When The user clicks on the links within the Help page
    Then The user is navigated to that Help section
```

**HelpStep.java**

```
@Ignore
public class HelpStep {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public HelpStep() {
        this.driver = Hooks.driver;
    }

    @Given("^The user is on the Help page$")
    public void onPage() {
        System.out.println("The user is on the Help page");
    }

    @When("^The user clicks on the links within the Help page$")
    public void clickLinks() {
        System.out.println("The user clicks on the links within the Help page");
    }

    @Then("^The user is navigated to that Help section$")
    public void validate() {
        System.out.println("The user is navigated to that Help section");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specific the before and after hooks with tag for every Feature, Why ? ok for example you have two features called `UsersFeature` and `ProductsFeature` and you make some hooks like initBrowser as before and closeBrowser as after for UsersFeature and ProductsFeature what happens when you run that test without any tags ? let me tell you that hooks it will running for tow times or (N times for parallel) for every Feature for that test and `N = "number of the features in that test"` so all the before hooks in that test will runing first even if there is million Features and also the all the after hooks so make sure use tags like `@Before('@users_feature') @After('@users_feature')` in that time that hooks will runing only when the test executing the feature scenarios with `@users_feature tag`